# slim 3 middleware & psr-4 composer autoloader: class not found

Tags: php, composer-php, slim, autoloader, psr-4

**composer.json**:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/"
    }
},
```

**src/Auth/RequestMethodPathRule.php:**

```
namespace App\Auth;
class RequestMethodPathRule implements  \Slim\Middleware\HttpBasicAuthentication\RuleInterface 
{ 
...
```

**src/middleware.php**

```
$app->add(new \Slim\Middleware\HttpBasicAuthentication([
    "rules" => [new App\Auth\RequestMethodPathRule(
```

This results in

> Class 'App\Auth\RequestMethodPathRule' not found.

Including all of the code in *RequestMethodPathRule.php* in the file *middleware.php* works fine.

More strangely, along with the 500 error, the browser displays the source code of RequestMethodPathRule.php!

**EDIT:**
Oh my, I had a shorttag on the class file `(<? instead of <?php)` so php treated it as text. Habits are hard to quit.

Comment: `config.json`, are you sure that's the name of the file?

Comment: meant composer.json. I will edit thanks.

Comment: Wait, did you forgot the `<?php` tag?

Comment: @Federkun yes, close, you got it! Oh how many lost hours. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> More strangely, along with the 500 error, the browser displays the source code of RequestMethodPathRule.php!

That's mean that composer correctly include the file, but no class is found because the code isn't interpret by php. In this case, since the short tags aren't a usually enabled, you just need to replace them with the `<?php` tag instead.